# Noscript tag's content being displayed even though JavaScript is enabled?

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a very simple snippet of HTML (below) - and both sections seem to be enabled - the script runs *and* the noscript tag's content shows.  What's going on here?

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  // script omitted
</SCRIPT>

<NOSCRIPT>
  <IMG SRC="image.jpg" WIDTH=1 HEIGHT=1 BORDER=0 ALT=""/>
</NOSCRIPT>
```

Comment: Which browser are you checking this in?

Comment: Doesn't matter. This works with all browsers in the universe.

Comment: Is the browser serving the cached copy?

Comment: Not that this would solve the problem, but I have this urge to fix your markup.  SCRIPT, NOSCRIPT, and IMG should be lowercase.  And there should be a space before the ending / on the IMG line.  This will make it valid XHTML, since that's what you're going for here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose it has something to do with the "// script omitted" part..

i.e.

```
<SCRIPT blah blah>

    var x = "</SCRIPT>"; // <--- Whoops?
```

And by "very simple snippet", is it a full HTML page or just the SCRIPT and NOSCRIPT tags?

Try:

```
<HTML><BODY>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  // script omitted
</SCRIPT>

<NOSCRIPT>
  <IMG SRC="image.jpg" WIDTH=1 HEIGHT=1 BORDER=0 ALT=""/>
</NOSCRIPT>
</BODY></HTML>
```

And see if there is any difference..

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know as well as I that shouldn't happen.

You're sure there arent any mismatched start/end-tags or something? Or that you accidentally put the same image somewhere else too, outside the noscript tag?

There's bound to be some error in the page that doesn't show in your nicely cleaned up snippet (and I suspect you'll be embarassed when you find it ;-).

I suggest you post a link to it or something.

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? I cannot reproduce this behavior in FF3 or IE7. Are you sure the script itself isn't displaying the same image?

Answer (score 0):

I can't duplicate the problem.  But my first guess is that it's simply caused by some malformed HTML.

One suggestion would be to run it through the [W3C XHTML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) and see what it says.

Comment: No doctype would induce that kind of behavior!

Comment: The more I thought about it, the more I think you're right.  I removed any mention of doctype from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Where did the `<NOSCRIPT>` element being placed at? If you placed it inside `<head>` tag, try to put it somewhere out of `<head>` tag. 
`<NOSCRIPT>` is unreliable, so you might think the other way around to address your need. PE or GD anyone?